# Compare Key to Array and get the result

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array variable

```
$usersColor = array
        (   
            "nica" => "blue",   
            "rejie" => "red", 
            "evan" => "green"   
        );
```

Suppose I have this code..

```
    <div class='nica' style="color:(user array color)"> </div> //shoud be the color of nica
```

How will I compare and get the corresponding user div color with the given key?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this, since you *know* that it is `nica`:

```
<div class='nica' style="color:<?=$usersColor['nica']?>"> </div>
```